# Ошибка lateinit property binding has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, android-data-binding, mvvm-android

Хочу перенести приложение для заметок из `Activity` в `Fragment`. В `Activity` все работало без ошибок, но как перенес начались проблемы. При запуске и выборе фрагмента приложение вылетает и выдает `lateinit property binding has not been initialized`, как это исправить?

```
class PlannedEvFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_planned_ev){
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentPlannedEvBinding
    private lateinit var noteViewModel: NoteViewModel
    private lateinit var adapter: NoteRecyclerViewAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val dao = NoteDatabase.getInstance(activity!!.application).noteDAO
        val repository = NoteRepository(dao)
        val factory = NoteViewModelFactory(repository)
        noteViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(NoteViewModel::class.java)

        binding.noteViewModel = noteViewModel    <-- на этой строчке выдает ошибку

        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        displayNoteList()
        initRecyclerView()

        nnoteViewModel.message.observe(this, Observer {
            it.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let {
                Toast.makeText(activity!!.application, it, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }

    private fun initRecyclerView(){
        adapter = NoteRecyclerViewAdapter({ selectedItem: Note -> listItemClicked(selectedItem) })
        binding.noteRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        binding.noteRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
        displayNoteList()
    }

    private fun displayNoteList(){
        noteViewModel.notes.observe(this, Observer {
            Log.i("MYTAG", it.toString())
            adapter.setList(it)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
    }
    private fun listItemClicked(note: Note){
        noteViewModel.initUpdateAndDelete(note)
    }
}
```

Фрагмент:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="noteViewModel"
            type="com.example.taskmanager.view.NoteViewModel" />

    </data>
```

Comment: Ошибка тут `private lateinit var binding`. Вы объявили эту переменную, но ей ничего не было присвоено.  Однако в той строчке, где выдает ошибку Вы обращаетесь к `binding` так, как будто оно имеет реальное значение.

Comment: Кажется, понял, откуда ноги проблемы растут, хотя и не уверен на все 100. Binding не использовал никогда. Перенесите весь этот код из `onCreate` в метод `onViewCreated`. В методе `onCreate` фрагмент еще не создан до конца.

Comment: Перенес, так же ошибка всплывает

Comment: Ошибка может возникать из-за activity!!.application ? До того как переносил аргументом указывал просто application

Comment: С базой данных у этой ошибки нет решительно никакой связи

Comment: У Вас должен соответствующий `binding` находиться в верстке фрагмента, которую Вы возвращаете в `onCreateView`, покажите, пожалуйста, этот метод и верстку в вопросе

Comment: добавил биндинг и методы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Необходимо добавить метод onCreateView(). В нем инициализировать binding :

   ```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layoutId, container, false)

    return binding.root
    }
   ```
2. Необходимо вынести логику из метода onCreate в метод onViewCreated()

   ```
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val dao = NoteDatabase.getInstance(activity!!.application).noteDAO
    val repository = NoteRepository(dao)
    val factory = NoteViewModelFactory(repository)
    noteViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(NoteViewModel::class.java)

    binding.noteViewModel = noteViewModel

    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    displayNoteList()
    initRecyclerView()

    nnoteViewModel.message.observe(this, Observer {
        it.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let {
            Toast.makeText(activity!!.application, it, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Я не очень хорошо знаком с *Data Binding*, но, думаю я знаю где ваша проблема.

Ошибка `lateinit property binding has not been initialized` говорит о том, что есть некоторое поле (в вашем случае `binding` которое не инициализированно, т.е. `null`).

Тут есть 2 варианта:

- Либо вы в принципе не вызвали методы инициализации `binding` в коде. Я их не вижу, поэтому вполне вероятно, что ваша проблема лежит здесь.
- Но тут может быть такое, что система делает это под капотом (это к тому, что я не знаю как правильно должны инициализироваться биндинги в *Data Bindnig*). Если вы говорите, что данный код работал в `Activity` успешно, то скорее всего вам нужно перенести всю инициализацию (в частности любые вызовы `binding`) любой колбек жизненного цикла фрагмента начиная с `onViewCreated()` или более поздний.

  Связано это с тем, что в Activity ваша View вам доступна уже в методе `onCreate()` после вызова `setContentView()` и там ваш биндинг мог обратиться ко `View`. Во фрагменте в методе `onCreate()` никакой `View` еще не существует, макет раздувается в методе `onCreateView()` и готов к использованию уже в `onViewCreated()`